# CodeIgniter access base_url() inside error_404.php

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

When 404 Page Not Found error occurs `application/errors/error_404.php` template is used in CodeIgniter. I need to access the `base_url()` function inside that template. Any suggestion on how `base_url()` or `site_url()` functions can be accessed inside `error_404.php` will be really helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you might want to use this simple trick. Just change the code below:

```
<?php echo base_url() ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo config_item(‘base_url’); ?>
```

credit for https://www.petanikode.com/codeigniter-base-url-404/
this work for my case

Answer (score 7):

Try following in `application/errors/error_404.php`

```
$CI =& get_instance();
if( ! isset($CI))
{
    $CI = new CI_Controller();
}
$CI->load->helper('url');
echo $CI->base_url();
```

Comment: Already tried. It results into - Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\developer-tools\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 234.

Comment: Glad I found this. So annoying that the CI instance drops out inside default error templates! +1

Comment: @Utkanos I think it's like this by design - what if the error occurs before Codeigniter gets a chance to be bootstrapped? Then even your get_instance() call will also return an error..

Comment: @digout - well for errors that occur at a PHP level, before CI is initiated, sure. But these are error pages served BY CI, therefore it's more than reasonable to expect access to the instance.

Comment: @Utkanos no CI could still initiate and yet not be able to load() anything. Had it before.

Comment: echo $CI->base_url(); gives Call to undefined method CI_Controller::base_url() You may use echo base_url(); instead

Answer (score 7):

Try this in top of your 404 page:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
if( ! isset($CI))
{
    $CI = new CI_Controller();
}
$CI->load->helper('url');
echo base_url();

// below here base_url(), site_url() will work
```

Work for all pages under **views/errors/html** folder

Comment: Awesome solution

Comment: If you have autoloaded url helper you don't need $CI->load->helper('url');

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use these functions, because these are global functions.
eg: you are in `404 page template`

```
<html> 
<head>
  <title> 404 Error </title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo base_url('/your path'); ?>
  <?php echo site_url('/your path'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited**

goto your `application/config/autoload.php` file and add `url` in autoload array

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

after this you can directly use `<?php echo base_url('/your path'); ?>` everywhere

Comment: Using these functions directly result into "Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url()"

Comment: which Codeigniter version you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your /application/config/routes.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'your_controller/error';
```

Add function into your_controller.php

```
function error(){
    show_404();   
}
```

You are ready to go.

Comment: I think this is the better solution than modify the error_404 file

Answer (score 1):

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48033542/7840849
or do followings
$autoload['helper'] = array('url'); in **application\config\autoload.php** file

Then simply use  echo config_item('base_url'); instead of  echo base_url(); in **codeigniter default error pages**

Answer (score 0):

$autoload['helper'] = array('url'); in **application\config\autoload.php** file

Then simply use  echo config_item('base_url'); instead of  echo base_url(); in **codeigniter default error pages**

Answer (score 0):

this work for my case, try this method

Change the function base_url() to config_item('base_url')

```
    <?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In order to use base_url(), you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in application/config/autoload.php

$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
Or, manually:

$this->load->helper('url');
Once it's loaded, be sure to keep in mind that base_url() doesn't implicitly print or echo out anything, rather it returns the value to be printed:

echo base_url();

Check if you have something configured inside the config file /application/config/config.php e.g.
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';

**Then** 
u can use like this..
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/template/default.css" type="text/css" />
```